# Flow: No error using an import with flow comments

Tags: javascript, reactjs, static-analysis, flowtype, flow-typed

I'm working on a library that's setup to transform flow annotations into comments. I'm doing this so that consumers of the library can get type checking if they are using flow.

So right now I have an example project that's linked to the local version of the library. The example project is using flow, and it seems to work fine. But when I import a component from my library and pass invalid props to it, flow does not raise an error.

Here's the transpiled component that I'm importing:

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.default = Checkbox;

var _react = require('react');

var _react2 = _interopRequireDefault(_react);

var _Check = require('./Check');

var _Check2 = _interopRequireDefault(_Check);

var _types = require('./types');

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

function Checkbox(props /*: { input: BoolInputType, label: string }*/) /*: Element*/ {
  return _react2.default.createElement(
    'div',
    { className: 'form-group checkbox' },
    _react2.default.createElement(_Check2.default, props)
  );
}
```

And here's a component from my example project that uses that import.

```
// @flow

import React from 'react';
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';
import { Checkbox } from 'reformd';

export function Form() {
  return (
    <form>
      <Checkbox input="foo" />
      <Field name="hasLife" component={Checkbox} label="Got a life?" />
    </form>
  );
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'reformd'
})(Form);
```

I know flow is working because it was initially raising errors about the redux-form module being undefined. I fixed that by adding a minimal libdef in `/flow-types`. At that point I expect it to raise an error saying that I passed invalid props to `Checkbox`, but this never happens.

Aren't the flow comments supposed to be respected here? If not, what's the point of the transformation? It doesn't seem to matter whether I ignore my `node_modules` directory in my `.flowconfig` or not. No errors either way.